# i Had Error in react-native-volume implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I had this error when i try implementing react native volume in my application

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-volume:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Do you mean react-native-volume-control?

Comment: i am using react-native-volume , so when i run, it gives me the above error

Comment: Let me suggest you to use "react-native-volume-control" coz "react-native-volume" is not updated for so long.